# how to convert X.509 v1 certificate to X.509 version 3

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

how to convert X.509 v1 certificate to **X.509 version 3**

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"?

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** convert a x509v1 to a X509v3 certificate without reissuing. see [this post](http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg24211.html) on openssl-users for more information